# Show that $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i }= i$ - Problem to understand a certain convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

We have defined $e^{ix}=\cos x+ i \sin x$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I also have proved earlier that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ and know that $\sin(0)=0$

Now I want to prove that

$e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i }= i$

I know that

$|e^{xi }|= 1,\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$

Therefore

$1=|e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}|=|\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})|=|\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})|$

---

**And now the part that I don't understand**

Because $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)>0,\forall_{x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2})}$

$\Longrightarrow\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$

---

$\Longrightarrow e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i }= i$

Please explain me which Theorem we use here. And how this Situation can be generalised, so if I Encounter something similiar I directly know what to do

Edit:

Can it be shown constructively, i.e. with the mean-value-theorem for example?

Comment: "We have defined $e^{ix}=\cos x+ i \sin x$" - So just plug in $x =  \frac{\pi}{2}$ and you get $i$..

Comment: Is the point of your question to prove $\cos\frac\pi2=0$ and $\sin\frac\pi2=1$? What properties of sine and cosine are allowed to be known to this point?

Comment: The Addition Theorem and the differentials. We don't know anything About the periodicity , the Intention was to Show $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: Tell us what definition of sine/cosine is used.

Comment: $\cos x :=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$

Comment: $\sin x :=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: How is then $e^z$ defined?

Comment: $e^z:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}$

Comment: And what is the definition of $\pi$? It would be helpful to include all these definitions as well as your proofs of $\cos\frac\pi2=0$ or $|e^{ix}|=1$ in the question.

Comment: We have defined $\pi$ as the double of the smallest zeropoint of $\cos$

Comment: There is simply no way we can answer this question without having all you axioms, definitions, and contexts explained explicitly.

Comment: Your definitions of the trig functions $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are circular if you use the definition for $e^{ix}$ in the first sentence of this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially we need only to prove $\sin\frac\pi2>0$. The answer will use the mean value theorem (MVT) as asked in question.

The definition of $e^z,\sin z, \cos z$ implies that the functions are continuous and differentiable. Particularly:
$$
\forall z\in\mathbb C: \sin'z=\cos z.\tag1
$$

As $\frac\pi2$ is by definition (see discussion in comments) the least positive root of $\cos x$ and $\cos(0)=1>0$ we have from the continuity of the function:
$$
\forall x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right): \cos x>0.
$$

Together with (1) this implies:
$$
\forall x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right): \sin' x>0.\tag2
$$

Now by MVT there exists such a point $0<c<\frac\pi2$ that
$$
\sin'(c)=\frac{\sin\frac\pi2-\sin0}{\frac\pi2-0}
\implies \sin\frac\pi2=\frac\pi2\sin'(c).
$$
As both $\sin'(c)$ and $\frac\pi2$ are positive, we obtain $$\sin\frac\pi2>0.$$

Answer (score 2):

You know that $ \sin(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, so that 
$$\left\vert \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right\vert=1 \Rightarrow \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)= \pm1$$

If $\sin'(x)=\cos(x) >0$ for all $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, then this means that the sinus function is strictly growing on $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. With $\sin(0)=0$, with $\sin$ being an continuous function, then the only possibility is $$\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)=+1$$

Hence $$e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} = i$$

**Edit** If you want to proove that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$, so note that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left( e^{ix} \right) = ie^{ix} = i\cos(x) - sin(x)$$
Implies that 
$$ \cos'(x) + i\sin'(x) = -\sin(x) + i\cos(x)$$
Prooving that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$

Comment: But why is it the only possibility?

Comment: it can be only +1 or -1, because it is in $\mathbb{R}$. If the function is growing, starting at 0, it cannot be -1

Comment: Because otherwise it would contradict continuity, Right?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: I was wondering if one could Show the property with a constructive proof and not by contradiction because I feel like I should know some Theorems  by now which would imply the result directly

Comment: Like the mean-value-theorem for example, I was interested to see how it could be applied in here